# Alternate posts in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

In order to put ads on my WordPress site, but only every few posts, I want to add a simple conditional to the bottom of each post, containing my ad code.

I have something like the following:

```
<?php if (the_ID() % 3 == 0){ ?>
ad code

<?php } ?>
```

But all this does is echo the id of the post.... for EVERY post!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `the_ID` does is simply to *echo* the ID of the current post.

If you want to *get* the ID, use `get_the_ID()` instead.